# bootstrap nesting columns in a short-div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, nested

I am fairly new to bootstrap, I am trying to achieve something like this in the attached image but I can't get Text area 3 &4 to display.

Here is my code below
Any suggestions are welcome. I am looking for a good tutorial on the grid system too
Here is the link to the image

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <center>
            <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>

            <p>
                Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing
                responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
            </p>

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Order service ">

        </center>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8" >


            <!-- first row 8 div-->
            <div class="short-div">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing
                    responsive, mobile-first projects on the web. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing
                    responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- second row 8 div-->
            <div class="short-div">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing
                    responsive, mobile-first projects on the web. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing
                    responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
                </div>
            </div>


              <!-- third row 8 div-->
            <div class="short-div">

                <!--left 4 div-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color:forestgreen">

                </div>

                <!--right 4 div-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color:blue">

                </div>

            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Cthulhu Having 1.4k reputation in the site, you must see the question correctly and also be aware that people with 1 rep cannot post images!

Comment: I have now added a link to the attachment image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that when you want to subdivide a row, you need to calculate the width respect to 12 grid system of the parent element instead of the body.

Use `col-md-6` instead of `col-md-4` since it will divide the parent element into columns and not three.

Your required layout is in the code below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <center>
      <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>

      <p>
        Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
      </p>

      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Order service ">

    </center>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">


      <!-- first row 8 div-->
      <div class="short-div">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- second row 8 div-->
      <div class="short-div">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- third row 8 div-->
      <div class="short-div">

        <!--left 4 div-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 well">
          Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
        </div>

        <!--right 4 div-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 well">
          Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```